# Can't remove all element in java.util.Map.Entry

Tags: java, hashmap

In all element in Entry Map, I only can remove the one element at least position. Can anybody explain what reason ?

Ps: I think problem at EntryMap with HashMap

This is full code:

```
import java.util.HashMap;

import java.util.Map;

import java.util.Map.Entry;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Neti {

    static Map<Integer, String> mm = new HashMap<>();

    static void removeEntry(Integer val) {

        for (Entry<Integer, String> entry : mm.entrySet()) {

            if (entry.getKey() == val) {

                mm.remove(val);

                break;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
         mm.put(123, "one");
         mm.put(1234, "two");
         mm.put(12345, "three");
         mm.put(123456, "four");

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("We have: " + mm);
        for (;;) {
            System.out.print("Number to remove: ");

            int val = scanner.nextInt();

            removeEntry(val);
            System.out.println("Map entries are: " + mm.toString());
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: use equals instead of == to compare Integers

Comment: @Eran: thanks :D, but why i use == it don't run true ?

Comment: `==` compares references. If you create two `Integer` instances having the same value (assuming it's not within the range of the IntegetCache, which is -128 to 127), they are not the same object, so `==` returns false even though they have the same `int` value.

Answer (score 3):

Your entire `removeEntry` method can be replaced by a single statement - `mm.remove(val)`. There's no need to iterate over the `entrySet` to find the key you wish to remove, and even if there was, using `==` for reference types is usually wrong.